# Using the view of the Mac's camera in my app

Tags: macos, camera

I am having trouble finding documentation with regards to the Mac camera. I am trying to activate the camera and display it in my application. I believe I have to use iSight, but then again couldn't find anything helpful. Any pointers?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=camera turns up [`IKCameraDeviceView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Quartz/Reference/IKCameraDeviceView_Class/), which looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageSnap](http://iharder.net/imagesnap) is a little utility which takes pictures via iSight. Source code is available at the web site.

Comment: thank you very much,do you know if there is a more efficient way to stream videos rather than frame by frame?